# Onde deve ficar a regra de negócio no padrão MVC?

Tags: mvc, design-pattern

Há algumas semanas comecei a estudar a fundo ASP.NET MVC e, como eu vim do Windows Forms, tem algumas coisas que não ficaram muito claras ainda.

Em todas as aplicações que fiz até hoje nesse padrão nunca me preocupei muito em onde a regra de negócio deve ficar concentrada. Na maior parte das vezes, deixava a regra de negócio da aplicação no *controller* ou criava uma "classe intermediária" que faria isso. Exemplo:

Model cliente

```cs
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Classe intermediária

```cs
public class ClienteService
{
    private Cliente _cliente;

    public ClienteService(Cliente cliente)
    {
        _cliente = cliente;
    }

    public void AlgumaRegraDeNegocioExtremamenteComplexa()
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

Minhas dúvidas são as seguintes:

- Esse é o padrão ou o recomendável a se usar?
- O certo seria deixar toda a regra de negócio no *controller*?
- Existe algum *design pattern* que defina isso?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Não é aconselhável colocar as regras de negócio em um serviço, isto é, criar uma camada de serviço para isso.

Existe uma grande discórdia se deve ser colocado no model ou no controlador (**M** ou **C** do MVC).

Como dito pela resposta do [@Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/114099/20615) existem duas premissas para utilizar a lógica no modelo:

> - Usarei essa mesma lógica em dois ou mais lugares do meu código?
> - A separação representa algum ganho real na minha aplicação que
>   justifica o aumento da complexidade?

Eu adicionarei mais duas que são:

- Testes de código;
- Compartilhamento de modelos entre sistemas;

Para realizar testes de sistemas é normal fazer testes unitários diretamente no modelo, ignorando o controlador (claro, existe testes unitários no controlador também, mas este não é a questão aqui). Com isso, sendo mais fácil de testar.
E se sua ideia é compartilhar o código com outras aplicações, ou colocar um REST junto, quem sabe, você teria que replicar esses dados no controlador.

**Mas então devo fazer a lógica no modelo?**

Terá pessoas defendendo isso mais do que defende a família. Mas minha resposta é "depende".
Tudo depende do que você quer fazer.

Um exemplo simples são as [DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=net-7.0), que são colocadas no Modelo. E são regras de negócio.

Existem casos de pessoas utilizarem Repository Pattern para fazer regras de negócio, o que não tem como mensurar o quão errado está, mas existem casos.

O [Blog da Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20160301164154/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx) possui um artigo muito bom sobre as "Melhores Práticas" para se usar Asp.NET MVC. É um pouco antigo, mas muitas coisas se aplicam até hoje.

**Mas você falou tão bem de validação no Modelo, devo fazer lá então?**

Eu não falei bem, apontei fatos que são utilizados.

Devemos ter em mente que "Lógica de Negócio" é um termo amplo. Existem lógicas de modelo e lógicas de aplicação.

O controlador deve ter as lógicas referentes a entrada de dados e o que ele irá realizar.

Vamos analisar o projeto [MusicStore](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) da própria Microsoft.

Se observarmos o controller `ManageController` iremos ver que ele possui verificações que são consideradas lógicas de negócio, assim como o Identity possui lógicas que são colocadas no `IdentityConfig.cs`.

Sua aplicação pode ter regras de negócio deferente a tempo de acesso, limite de requisições, dentre outras. Isso são regras de negócio, ou não? Isso são coisas que o Modelo não precisa saber, não concorda?

**Concluindo**

Se sua regra pertence especificamente ao domínio, coloque no domínio, mas de uma forma que o `controller` entenda, para poder utilizar o que o Asp.NET MVC lhe proporciona de bom e dar uma resposta rápida ao usuário. DataAnnotations são excelentes para isso.
Se sua regra pertence a aplicação, nem pense no domínio, ele não tem nada a ver com isso.
E as validações que envolvam conferência de dados entre Models devem ser feitas em Controller ou através de classes estáticas (Helpers), como o [@Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114084/onde-deve-ficar-a-regra-de-neg%C3%B3cio-no-padr%C3%A3o-mvc/114156#comment238180_114156) explica.

Comment: Sobre isso aqui: "Mas você falou tanto de validação no Modelo, devo fazer lá então?", regra de validação inerente apenas ao próprio *Model* deve sim ser feita no *Model*. Os atributos, como você mesmo disse, seguem essa premissa. Validações que envolvam conferência de dados entre *Models* devem ser feitas em *Controller* ou através de classes estáticas (*Helpers*).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que o "Não" realmente ficou forte nesta colocação. Minha intenção não era essa. Sobre os *Helpers* eu concordo, esqueci de comentar o nome, mas espero que não ligue de ter "copiado" seu texto. :p

Comment: Um grande problema que vejo e que comentei na resposta são de pessoas utilizando *Helpers* como ser fosse um *Service* ou utilizando *Repository* como se fosse um *Helper*.

Answer (score 15):

## Onde deve ficar a regra de negócio no padrão MVC?

> Se realmente houver lógica de negócio, e principalmente se ela for complexa, ela deve ficar no **Model**.

A preocupação que a criação do pattern MVC (lá nos anos 1970) tentava resolver é a separação entre apresentação e lógica de negócio, e **o controller na maiorida das vezes está bastante acoplado com a apresentação**.

Veja este [desenho do Fowler representando o MVC](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html):

[image: Relação entre os componentes no pattern MVC]

Repare que a View conhece o Controller, que também conhece a View; e repare que o Model não conhece ninguém.

No seu livro [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321127420), Fowler diz:

> "A separação entre apresentação e model é uma das mais fundamentais heurísticas do bom design de software."

Neste mesmo livro, ele menciona que **a separação entre Controller e View pode não ser tão evidente em muitos designs**, e que isso não é um problema, é natural elas se confundirem.

E se confundem mesmo: note como o Controller de fato precisa conhecer a View, ele conhece as regras de apresentação (inclusive é ele quem define estas regras).

Esta intimidade entre o Controller e a View já são um indício de que o Controller não é boa companhia para a lógica de negócio (diga-me com quem andas e eu te direi quem és) caso você queira realmente separar estes conceitos.

## Mas o que é afinal "lógica" ou "regra" de negócio?

O StackOverflow precisa mostrar antes as respostas com mais votos. Isso é uma regra de negócio? Certamente é, este é um princípio core da ferramenta.

O StackOverflow não pode admitir uma pergunta sem título. Isso também é uma regra de negócio.

Então estas regras precisam estar no Model? Não precisam e provavelmente não estejam. Estas são regras de negócio muito simples, que podem ser resolvidas na apresentação.

O SO, uma ferramenta tão importante, com tantos usuários, possivelmente nem tem uma camada de domínio concentrando suas regras de negócio com alta abstração. É possível que Models por aqui sejam apenas DTOs representando no sistema os dados do banco de dados.

O SO provavelmente é um exemplo de sistema que se classifica como de baixa complexidade de regras de negócio, onde uma abstração do domínio numa camada pode ser desnecessário e até danoso.

A maioria dos projetos que participei até hoje, entretanto, tinham regras de negócio complexas o suficiente e necessidade suficiente de reutilização que justificavam uma abordagem de design mais elaborada. Mas com certeza absoluta nem todos os sistemas justificam tal abordagem! Não vou falar em "maioria" de maneira geral porque não tenho dados estatísticos. Eu só posso falar do meu próprio contexto.

## Se decida, meu filho: as regras podem ou não ficar no Controller?

Podem se o sistema tiver regras simples, regras basicamente de apresentação.

Não deveriam se o sistema tiver regras complexas, um domínio complexo, e alta necessidade de reutilização (as regras precisam estar disponíveis para mais de um tipo de consumidor - como usuário final, fachada de serviços, outros serviços de negócio do próprio sistema, integrações, bases de código de outros sistemas, etc).

Vou deixar a resposta com o Fowler (retirada do livro já mencionado):

> "O valor do MVC reside em suas duas separações. Destas, a separação entre apresentação e model é um dos mais importantes princípios do design de software, e o único momento em que você não deveria segui-la é em sistemas muito simples onde o model não tem comportamento real nele.
>
> Tão logo você tenha alguma lógica não visual, você deveria aplicar a separação.
>
> Infelizmente, um monte de frameworks de UI tornam esta separação difícil, e os que não tornam quase sempre são ensinados sem a separação.
>
> A separação entre view e controller é menos importante, então eu só recomendaria fazê-la quando fosse realmente útil."

Comment: Então esta resposta está fundamentada apenas no Fowler? A resposta sim, mas minha motivação em escrevê-la está fundamentada em muitas outras fontes e na experiência pessoal. O Fowler entra na jogada porque o povo gosta de referências confiáveis na resposta ;-)

Answer (score 13):

> Esse é o padrão ou o recomendável a ser?

O recomendável é sempre o que é mais simples ou mais rápido. Se a separação é necessária por algum motivo, vá pelo caminho da separação. Pessoalmente falando, raramente faço essa separação de regras de negócio em camadas intermediárias porque não há motivo nos meus sistemas para que isso aconteça.

Um bom motivo para a separação no caso do ASP.NET MVC5 é quando você tem que implementar uma camada REST (Web API) e uma camada MVC com as mesmas regras. Como os *Controllers* de cada arquitetura são muito diferentes entre si, a separação se justifica. Caso contrário, não há necessidade da separação.

> O certo seria deixar toda a regra de negócio no controller?

Na grande maioria dos casos, sim. Há duas premissas gerais que podem ser usadas para decidir isso:

- Usarei essa mesma lógica em dois ou mais lugares do meu código?
- A separação representa algum ganho real na minha aplicação que justifica o aumento da complexidade?

Na grande maioria dos casos, a resposta é "não", mas aviso que há um movimento de pessoas que vão pelo "sim" (principalmente aqui no Brasil) mesmo sem apresentar motivos concretos para isso. Motivos concretos vão além de simplesmente "vou melhorar a modularidade do meu código", ou ainda "definirei melhor as responsabilidades de cada componente". Esse tipo de decisão compromete fortemente toda a cadeia produtiva, porque adiciona elementos que aumentam a complexidade sem necessidade real para isso. Ninguém troca o ORM do sistema todo uma vez por mês, ou de injetor de dependência.

Se nos próprios modelos de componentes a Microsoft parte para a simplificação, significa que remar na direção contrária vai contra a premissa de produtividade do próprio fornecedor do *framework*. Um exemplo disso é que os modelos de *Scaffold* para repositório já não são mais distribuídos juntamente com o Visual Studio desde a versão 2013.

> Existe algum design pattern que defina isso?

Um *Controller* não deixa de ser um *Design Pattern*. Um *Model* também não. Fiz um exercício de mapeamento de padrões de design no ASP.NET MVC e o que obtive até hoje foi o seguinte:

- **Factory**: Criadores de *Controllers*;
- **Decorator**: Atributos de *Models* e *Controllers*;
- **Proxy**: Criação de objetos provisórios para carga preguiçosa quando usando Entity Framework;
- **Iterator**: Tudo que implementa `IEnumerable`;
- **Observer**: `DbContext` do Entity Framework;
- **State**: `DbEntityEntry` do Entity Framework;
- **Template Method**: Classes abstratas do ASP.NET MVC, como `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`;
- **Visitor**: geradores de consulta do Entity Framework.

Respondendo sua pergunta, dependendo da abordagem que você considera para a construção de padrões, o ASP.NET MVC implementa seus próprios padrões.