# Em um projeto MVC, onde devo deixar os enums?

Tags: java, mvc, estilo-de-codificação, enums

Estou desenvolvendo um programa com padrão MVC, precisei criar alguns `enum`, e deixei eles na camada *Model*, mas fiquei em dúvida sobre sua localização, qual seria a camada mais correta para abrigar os `enum` de um projeto?

Comment: Depende para que eles servem, Pode ser no modelo se eles são importantes ou fazem parte do modelo.

Comment: @bigown Eles só são usados nos controllers, então o certo seria colocá-los na camada Control ?

Comment: Dei uma resposta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sem conhecer o problema exato não dá para responder. É um absurdo qualquer pessoa dizer onde deve colocar algo sem o conhecimento da necessidade específica. Isso ocorre por causa da cultura da receita de bolo que não tem nada a ver com programação profissional.

Se as enumerações fazem parte do modelo, se elas são parte da regra do negócio que está montando, então o normal é estar no modelo. Só quem está criando a aplicação pode dizer isto.

Se as enumerações ajudam o funcionamento do controlador, então provavelmente é lá que deve colocar. Em geral isso é feito quando faz parte da regra da aplicação.

Há casos que não é para colocar em nenhum dos dois e até cabe uma separação extra (*helpers*). Precisa acabar com essa ideia que porque a aplicação tem 3 pastinhas, tem lugar certo para colocar as coisas. Até tem lugar certo, mas não é regra pronta, tem que colocar no local mais adequado.

[Sequer há consenso onde deve ir a regra de negócio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114084/101), e muitos dizem que deve ir no controlador. Então afirmar que algo vai em algum lugar sem conhecimento do caso é pura opinião sem fundamento.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).