# O que é a View no padrão MVC?

Tags: java, mvc, arquitetura-de-software, view

Comecei em 2016 a usar padrão *MVC*, o conceito de *Model* e *Controller* entendo perfeitamente, mas a questão de *View* me intriga.

O que é a *View* em um modelo *MVC*?

Sei que é o que o cliente vê *(representação dos dados)*, mas o que pode ser entendido como parte de uma *View*?

E no caso de uma aplicação separada para a interface do cliente, posso considerar essa como a camada de *View*?

Em outras palavras: O que faz parte da *View* no lado do servidor falando em desenvolvimento *Web*?

Comment: View é a GUI. Ex. simplista: em aplicações web, view é o HTML.

Comment: @jbueno mas é somente o HTML?

Comment: Sim. A View é a "visão" a sua interface gráfica, entende? Aquilo que o usuário vai ver.

Comment: Relacionada: [Onde deve ficar a regra de negócio no padrão MVC?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114084/18246)

Comment: De forma simples e objetiva: `View` é o que o usuário vê. Não faz nada na parte de servidor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> O que é a View em um modelo MVC?

*View* é a apresentação de dados, é a saída, é como o usuário irá ver o que foi produzido por uma ação da aplicação, e é a forma como uma entrada de dados ocorrerá e iniciará uma ação por parte do usuário.

**MVC não pressupõe que use uma arquitetura cliente-servidor**, portanto usar esses termos não faz sentido a não ser que o MVC esteja sendo usado em uma aplicação web com essa arquitetura. O MVC pode até mesmo ser aplicado só do lado do cliente, e tecnicamente quando é usado no lado do servidor, ele é todo no servidor, afinal a *view* é apenas a criação da página HTML. Mesmo que o contexto seja este, usar as palavras "cliente" e "servidor" é algo pontual e nada tem a ver com o padrão.

Então a separação das camadas em instâncias diferentes da solução é possível, até porque o modelo pode estar em um servidor, o controlador pode estar em outro, gerador da visão pode estar em outro, assim como o *renderizador* dessa visão pode estar em outro dispositivo (pode ser um cliente).

**Não existe nada que determine que ela deva gerar HTML, XML, JSON, ou coisa do tipo**. Pode gerar uma forma proprietária de comunicação, algo como uma caixa preta que só interessa para aquela aplicação.

> o que pode ser entendido como parte de uma View?

Ela costuma ser o mecanismo que determina o que será renderizado para o cliente, mas não costuma ser o mecanismo de renderização (desenho efetivo). Então nele tem principalmente o que será apresentado, com quais características e a maneira como o usuário deve interagir com aquilo.

É comum ela possuir alguma lógica de aplicação, principalmente de aplicação e mecanismos de contato com outras camadas. O recomendado é minimizar tudo isso e deixar o máximo que der só a apresentação. Claro que não a custo de prejudicar a experiência com o usuário.

**É possível que a *view* se comunique com o *model***, nada no padrão determina que isso seja proibido. É comum que se evite isso, e recomendado. Mas de forma geral todos esses *frameworks* pressupõem forte acoplamento entre as partes. Na teoria não deveria ter, mas na prática é impossível não ter. Mexeu alguma coisa no modelo, é comum ter que mexer no controlador e principalmente na visão. O [diagrama retirado da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) mostra claramente que eles se comunicam:

[image: MVC]

O Martin Fowler, que costuma ser respeitado sobre esses assuntos de arquitetura, [mostra em sua página que a comunicação pode ocorrer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController).

Note que em ambos artigos não falam em HTML ou semelhantes, muito menos de cliente-servidor. Na verdade o padrão é muito mais antigo que a web. O fato dele ser popular com essa tecnologia não significa que ele só deve ser usado assim.

> no caso de uma aplicação separada para a interface do cliente, posso considerar essa como a camada de View?

É possível, mas não necessariamente. Esse é um caso que se tem um arquitetura cliente-servidor verdadeira e o cliente pode não ter conhecimento de nada de como o servidor funciona, só sabe se comunicar genericamente com ele. Nesse caso ela não é uma *view*. Para a *view* funcionar ela pressupõe a existência de pelo menos um *controller* que interaja com ela. Isso ocorre na maioria de sites web, mas nem tanto em aplicações web. Na verdade tem muita aplicação web que o próprio cliente é um MVC por si só e o servidor no máximo tem um modelo e um controlador, nada de visão. Costuma ocorrer o mesmo em aplicações desktop e mobile.

> O que faz parte da View no lado do servidor falando em desenvolvimento Web?

É a montagem do HTML, em geral feito através de *templates*, mas não necessariamente. A *view* não é a renderização no cliente. E se fosse, teria duas *views*? Não pode, e nem faz sentido.

Quando usa-se Angular ou algo parecido tem gente que acha que a *view* é o cliente. Não faz sentido, seu funcionamento é completamente independente.

Não é muito detalhe, mas a pergunta não é muito específica :)

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: @bigown muito boa a resposta...

Comment: @JcSaint mas diz o oposto do que você disse.

Comment: @bigown não vejo por que vai parecer que você está errado, sua resposta também teve uma boa aceitação até por que foi bem completa, e não me parece dizer completamente o oposto, talvez na primeira resposta se pudesse complementar com algo como "Exemplificando em um sistema Web seria o HTML", ambas as respostas me serviram para tirar a dúvida, e acredito que ambas também vão valer a pena de se ler no SO :)

Comment: Quando uma resposta cheia de erros e que diz o oposto da minha é aceita, ela começa receber mais votos, não deveria ser assim, mas é, aí quem lê vê a aceita e mais votada e acha que ela é a correta. Eu negritei o que é o oposto. Você pode aceitar o que quiser, não posso dizer nada quanto a isso, embora eu considero um desserviço nesse caso. O que vou te dizer é para não aceitar a primeira resposta que alguém dá correndo, mesmo que seja uma resposta minha, sempre espere por outras, você induz as pessoas votarem e se está perguntando talvez não saiba avaliar bem, melhor esperar por mais opções.

Comment: @bigown certo, tomarei esse cuidado na próxima, porém acredito que o fato de se dar um exemplo em uma aplicação web não comprometa toda a resposta, até por que minha pergunta pendeu pro lado web.

Comment: @FelipePaetzold um exemplo não é um problema, desde que fique claro que não é só isso. Nada na sua pergunta indica que é para web. Se era isso, acho que a pergunta deve ser fechada como não clara.

Comment: A resposta foi muito boa. Mas eu preferiria que ela fosse dada mais focada em continuar definindo o "V" do MVC, do que em apontar os erros da outra resposta na pergunta. Caso contrário ela corre o risco de se tornar apenas uma parte de um contexto maior, ao invés de conseguir se sustentar sozinha, o que é o objetivo do site.

Comment: @Gabe Ela se sustenta sozinha, inclusive porque quase toda ela foi escrita antes da outra resposta existir. Isso era o que eu queria responder. Só ressaltei os pontos que era opostos depois que li a outra e acrescentei referência. Até pendei em colocar mais coisas para reforçar esses pontos, mas achei que estava bom assim. Ainda posso melhorar alguma coisa, mas a resposta é bem forte para se sustentar. Eu poderia defender mais, mas você não gostaria do que eu tenho a dizer, então vou deixar uma defesa genérica.

Comment: @bigown Acredito que tenha sido sua intenção mas, honestamente, não é a impressão que ficou ao lê-la. Eu gostaria muito de vê-la retrabalhada, porque o potencial é enorme.

Comment: Eu só posso dizer sobre o que eu fiz, sobre a impressão que as outras pessoas têm eu não tenho controle. Eu até vou melhorar, as a resposta é esta.

Comment: @bigown está corretíssimo, só acho que você se envolveu demais no MVC e saiu do foco da explicação da view. Mas é uma ótima resposta.

Comment: @IvanFerrer eu ainda vou melhorar, mas quando eu puder fazer com calma.

Answer (score 20):

> O que é a View em um modelo MVC?

Parte da resposta dessa pergunta está na sua outra pergunta, quando afirma que *Sei que é o que o cliente vê (representação dos dados)*. Essa exibição pode ser via HTML, XML e em aplicações `Desktop` veja esse post [JAVA DESKTOP MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85875/11404).

> O que pode ser entendido como parte de uma View?

`View` toda a parte a ser exibida para o usuário.

> E no caso de uma aplicação separada para a interface do cliente, posso considerar essa como a camada de View?

Se a função dessa interface é somente mostrar dados, sim é a camada de `View` da sua aplicação...

> O que faz parte da View no lado do servidor?

Não faz nada, a camada de `View` não sabe da existência do banco de dados, e a camada de banco de dados não sabe da existência das `Views`. A camada de `Controller`é que faz essa "ponte" entre essas duas camadas. Apesar de ser possível acessar a camada de dados a partir das `Views`isso não é recomendado e foge do propósito do modelo do `MVC`

Sugiro ler:

- [MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx)
- [MVC](http://tableless.com.br/mvc-afinal-e-o-que/)
- [MVC Com Java](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/)
- [Artigo MVC JAVA Destktop](http://www.gqferreira.com.br/artigos/ver/mvc-com-java-desktop-parte1)

Comment: @JcSaint Da mesma forma um `Json` pode ser considerado parte da view?

Comment: Acho que o padrão independe da plataforma que vai ser desenvolvida, não?