# Diagrama de classe MVC

Tags: php, mvc, diagrama, diagrama-de-classes

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema web em php, onde todas as controllers estende suas respectivas models, por exemplo: tenho um usuarioController e um usuarioModel, minha dúvida é o seguinte, no diagrama de classe preciso representar os métodos da controller?.

Outra dúvida, meus métodos da model são todos protegidos, pois as controllers estende as models, isso esteticamente é errado?.

Answer (score 4):

O controller não deve estender o model. O controller está no nível de requisição (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` etc...) e o model está preocupado com persistência de dados (bancos, normalmente). Aqui no SO me falaram desse padrão para tratar do MVC chamado [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)) que explica bem o que cada coisa faz.

Pensa assim: o seu model não é necessariamente 1 pra 1 com o controller. O seu model de usuários vai incluir, alterar, apagar os usuários do banco de dados, o controller usuários não faz nada disso: ele teria que decidir se o usuário quer fazer login, por exemplo, e pedir pro model verificar se o usuário e senha que o programa recebeu batem com alguma entrada no banco.

Então se você fizer um diagrama, acredito que o controller é o primeiro ponto depois da requisição do usuário - e os métodos dele entram pra tomar a decisão com relação a isso - e em seguida ele delega alguma atividade pro model e responde com uma view, saca?

Essa ideia de 1 pra 1 simplesmente não funciona quando o sistema é mais "complexo". Por exemplo, se você vai cadastrar um cliente que tem vários endereços e telefones, cada um em sua tabela. Seu controller ou vai usar instâncias de 3 models (clientes, telefones, endereços), ou um dos models vai usar instâncias dos outros dois (clientes instancia telefones e endereços para incluir no banco).

Comment: Como comentei acima, não estou em dúvida do papel de cada componente, pois cada plataforma pode seguir um tipo de padrão, minha dúvida está na parte de criação do diagrama de classe, mesmo assim agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 4):

Controller e Model são duas coisas diferentes. O Controller pode herdar de outro Controller base, se houver necessidade, mas não da model.

No teu diagrama de classes, os métodos deverão ser os que a model disponibiliza, que o controller pode, ou não, consumir.

> A camada Model (modelo) representa a parte de sua aplicação que
>   implementa a lógica do negócio. Isto significa que ela é responsável
>   por obter os dados convertendo-os em conceitos significativos para sua
>   aplicação, assim como, processar, validar, associar e qualquer outra
>   tarefa relativa ao tratamento dos dados.
>
> https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html

Enquanto:

> A camada Controller (controlador) lida com as requisições dos
>   usuários. É responsável por retornar uma resposta com a ajuda das
>   camadas Model e View.
>   https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/cakephp-overview/understanding-model-view-controller.html

Comment: Veja bem, na estrutura que utilizo, todas as controllers estende suas respectivas models, onde na controller faço as regras de negocio de uma determinada entidade e na model faço todas parte de manuseio de dados da mesma. Não estou discutindo em si o significado e o papel de cada componente do sistema e sim, com base nessa arquitetura, como ficaria meu diagrama de classe. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @LourençonO. o que estamos falando é justamente que o conceito que você está usando (todo o controller estender um model) não condiz com o MVC. Se você curte programar assim, tudo bem, mas o conceito não está correto. Agora: quanto ao diagrama, acredito que "controller possui model" nesse caso.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é totalmente relativo, não importa necessariamente como o Controller leia os dados do Model ou como ele envie dados para o Model validar, o que importa é que apenas o controller tenha acesso ao Model, então se o que você explicou for exatamente isso

Mvc não depende diretamente da programação e muito menos de OOP, o MVC é como organiza o projeto, existem muitas perguntas sobre o assunto em [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc), existem muitos frameworks populares que "implementam" MVC, como [Laravel](https://laravel.com), mas mesmo se você usar Laravel não quer dizer que você irá usar MVC, pode ser que use o framework e faça algo que pela "lógica" não é nem de longe MVC.

Muito já se foi falado no site sobre MVC, alguns exemplos:

- [O que é MVC(Model, View, Controller)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/3635)
- [O que é MVP e MVVM?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21539/3635) (fala sobre a diferenças com MVC, o que pode ajudar)
- [O que é a View no padrão MVC?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168246/3635) (não é sobre PHP mas explica o papel do View)

A algum tempo atrás eu tive essa duvida sobre "WEB" e "MVC", trabalhando com 
Desktop, entender e aplicar MVC ou outros padrões de projeto me parece algo quase intuitivo, mas em web o conceito de comunicação direta "não existe", ao menos foi minha dificuidade:

- [Quando o controller é necessário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60830/3635)

Claro que se criar um framework bom a comunicação não direta irá ser quase direta, a questão da Web é que existem duas camadas, cliente-side e server-side, o qual usam o HTTP para se comunicar, então um Model popular uma View é mais trabalhoso, claro que o popular na verdade vai acontecer indiretamente, no caso de muitos frameworks os dados são adicionados ao Model pelo Controller e retornado ao Controller e então só depois disto são validados, no geral como disse vejo as pessoas usando o Model mais como um ORM do que como qualquer outra coisa.

### Concluindo

Agora vou falar uma coisa que é do meu ponto de vista, se você tem um Model amarrado a um Controller, então você só poderá ter um Model por Controller, isso ao meu ver parece um desperdício, ou melhor faz a organização com MVC ser quase desnecessária e provavelmente irá causar a repetição de códigos, um Model deveria ser aproveitável para vários Controllers, já que o intuito do Model é manipular os dados e validados (supostamente), então criar um Model para cada Controller seria melhor criar um ControllerModel tudo embutido mesmo, ainda sim seria pouco proveitoso e causaria a repetição de códigos.

Pense que o Model deve validar uma "algo", uma estrutura de dados seja qual for e devolver indiretamente o resultado (lembrando que é uma opinião minha), se esta mesma estrutura de dados for usada em vários lugares na maneira que você criou seu código você teria ou que reaproveitar um Controller várias vezes ou criar vários Models para uma mesma coisa com pequenas variações para cada situação, o que geraria a repetição que já citei.

Agora se você dividir o Model poderá usar mais de um Model em um Controller, eu sei que nem sempre vai precisar, mas pode haver a situação de 2 models se comunicarem.

> Torno a lembrar que este final é uma opinião de como criar a estrutura.

Comment: Boa conclusão. Penso exatamente que nem você.