# Estou utilizando (aprendi) o padrão MVC da maneira correta?

Tags: php, mvc

/*Olá. Há alguns anos na faculdade tive uma aula prática de padrões com PhP, e uma delas foi o MVC. Aprendi com meu professor o padrão MVC, mas não sei até hoje o mesmo foi ensinado da maneira correta. Sempre que vejo projetos com padrões MVC estão um pouco diferentes do meu, na verdade, a classe Controller parece não fazer muito sentido no que eu aprendi.
Gostaria que dessem uma olhada na forma que eu programo em MVC e dizer se estou fazendo da maneira correta ou se teria como melhorar, pois realmente estou perdido, principalmente na parte da Controller e da Model.

Na Model:

```
class ModelProduto{

private $id;
private $descricao;
private $valor;

public __construct(){
    // nada por aqui no momento...
}

protected function inserirProduto($produto){
    // realiza conexão com o banco
    // executa query no banco passando valores $produto->id, $produto->descricao, $produto->valor

    // retorna boolean se foi inserido com sucesso no banco ou nao
    return $resultado;
}

protected function buscarTodosProdutos(){
    // realiza conexão com o banco
    // traz os registros e armazenam em algum lugar, no caso, num array
    $produtos = new Array();
    foreach(resultado in lista){
        $produto = new Produto();
        $produto->id = resultado['id'];
        $produto->descricao = resultado['descricao'];
        $produto->valor = resultado['valor'];
        $produtos[] = $produto;
    }
    return $produtos;
}

// metodos Get e metodos Set em visibilidade public...
}
```

Feito isso, na Controller que é onde eu tenho mais dúvida, aprendi a estruturá-la da seguinte forma:

```
class Produto extends ModelProduto{

// as vezes aqui um método ou outro (geralmente static) para montar um objeto ou fazer algo extra
// sempre tenho a função de montar objetos para ser usada mais tarde
public static criaObj($descricao, $valor){
    $produto = new Produto();
    $produto->setDescricao($descricao);
    $produto->setValor($valor);
    return $produto;
}

public function inserirProduto($produto){
    return parent::inserirProduto()
}

public function buscarTodosProdutos(){
    return parent::buscarTodosProdutos()
}
}
```

Uma vez estruturado este MVC, na View, caso eu tenha um formulário para cadastrar este produto, ou exibí-lo, eu faço o seguinte:

```
<html>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="manipulaProduto.php">
            <!-- formulário aqui -->
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Consequentemente eu crio outro arquivo em outra pasta chamado manipula, onde eu verifico os dados dos formulários e mando pra controller, mais ou menos assim:

```
if(isset($_POST['formularioEnviado'])){
    inserir();
}

function inserir(){
    // crio variaveis para pgar os $_POST e validar os campos, verificar se não existem nulos, poucos caracteres etc
    $validado = validarCampos();
    if($validado){
        // se passar pelas validações, chamo o inserir do Controller
        $inserido = inserirProduto();

        if($inserido){
            // envio alguma modal para a view informando que tudo foi validado com sucesso e demais eventos se necessário
            return $inserido;
        }
    }

    // envio alguma modal para a view informando erro no formulario se não entrar no if
    return $erros;

}

function validarCampos(){
    // valida os campos e retorna para a função acima
}

function inserirProduto(){
    // chamo o Controller e crio um objeto
    $produto = Produto->criaObj($_POST["descricao"], $_POST["valor"])
    $resposta = $produto->inserirProduto($produto);
    return $resposta;
}
```

Esse é o padrão que eu utilizo em meus projeto. Não foi tudo que aprendi na faculdade, a maior parte eu desenvolvi minha maneira própria de programar, mas a questão é o padrão MVC. As vezes acho que esse manipulaProduto.php faz o papel que o Controller deveria fazer, pois o controller nada mais faz que transferir uma função para a Model, o que chega a ser quase inutil ao meu ver.
Podem me dizer como anda essa minha estrutura, se algo poderia ser melhorado ou se o padrão MVC está realmente errado? Lembrando que essa estrutura que criei aqui para apresentar meu problema é algo extremamente resumido e não cheguei a rodar os códigos, mas esta é a forma que programo atualmente.
Obrigado!

Comment: MVC não é OOP, não é algo que depende de como programa necessariamente, mas sim de como organiza. Tanto que é possivel usar MVC sem OOP, em Web MVC funciona diferente (note que MVC veio bem antes de web). Uma coisa que eu acho um grande erro (posso estar enganado) é que praticamente quase todos frameworks populares ou pessoa que usam MVC parece que pensam que o Model deve ser exclusivamente um ORM. Agora vou lhe dizer o que sempre digo sobre MVC, use se necessário, se não for necessário não tem porque usar, tem muito site simples que usam frameworks pesados, MVC e etc totalmente sem...

Comment: ... necessidade. MVC é um padrão de organização e tem um objetivo, que é fazer projetos médios e grandes que geralmente podem ter muitas pessoas trabalhando, conseguirem se guiar. Você pode usar um framework MVC popular e ainda sim usar de maneira não MVC que funcione de qualquer forma. Resumindo, tem necessidade de MVC? Então use. Não tem necessidade? Então não use. Quer entender o que é MVC? Então vá além do código, deve entender a necessidade e a comunicação. Qualquer resposta que afirma que esta correto ou é uma resposta opinativa já esta errada ;)

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a arquitetura MVC, seu modelo estaria correto. 
Você poderia pesquisar por padrões de projeto para ter outros pontos de vista sobre organização de código e do projeto em si. 
Separar as propriedades do seu model dos seus métodos, de serviços de conexão, serviços paralelos e etc.

Já seu controlador, ele não deveria herdar de um modelo. São coisas diferentes. Vai encontrar muitas discussões a respeito. Tem uma recente [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194474/diagrama-de-classe-mvc/195171)

Modelos devem conter sua regra de negócio
enquanto Controladores devem lidar com as requisições dos usuários e intermediar view e model.

O que não entendi foi isso:

> Consequentemente eu crio outro arquivo em outra pasta chamado
>   manipula, onde eu verifico os dados dos formulários e mando pra
>   controller

Porque você envia seu formulário pra um lugar que valida e depois envia pro controller? E também: que lugar é esse que valida?